# Jupyter and IRkernel - Avoid package loading messages

Tags: r, jupyter

How can I avoid the loading package messages when working in Jupyter (ipython notebook) and IRkernel?

For instance, if I try to load `reshape2` I see the following printer as an output.

> Loading required package: reshape2

I've installed IRkernel via Anaconda.

Comment: `?suppressPackageStartupMessages`

Comment: Is there any more general approach? I was looking for something like an `option` to set, so I don't take to use it every time I want to load a new package.